# Magento keeps falling back to base template

Tags: magento-1.9

My theme is called 'mytheme/custom' and theme should fallback to 'mytheme/default' before 'base/default', but for some reason, my Magento shop keeps falling back to 'base/default'.

I have tried to debug some of the core code to get a better idea of what is happening and after playing around with getFilename method within "/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php" it seems to me that automatically used 'base/default' unless code specifically loads 'mytheme/custom'...

Additionally, to that, I have noticed that one of my bootstrap observers is not being triggered, which is meant to attach on load. "https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate"

This is happening when I have moved Magento to a different hosting location, I have to assume that their might be some type of customization in place which prevents things working for a different domain name?

---

Update 1:
I have checked "System" -> "Configuration" -> "Advanced" and module is enabled, but when i added var_dump with exit to the observer, nothing  happens

---

Update 2:
I have found out that only default modules are being loaded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the cache. DB still was on the old server, so if I was to clear the cache, it will not take effect on the new server, due to which I had to clear it manually.